# Can a state and a function have the same name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I use the same name for the state and also the name of the function?

```
function BroadbandDeals() {
  const [broadbandDeals, setbroadbandDeals] = useState([]);
  return <div>Broadband Deals</div>;
}
```

Comment: ...does it work? (also, they don't have the same name, the component name is PascalCase while the state is camelCase)

Comment: Not sure it has yellow underline? I also thought that pascalcase and camelcase would make a difference

Comment: You can even create state with same name as component name, *but should you?* I don't think so, It is a bad practice

Comment: yeah it says "'broadbandDeals' is declared, but its value is never read."

Answer (score 3):

Technically in your case yes as they have different casing but if the casing matched then no you wouldn't be able to have the same name. Although I would say this is probably bad practice as it can make debugging more difficult as its quite common for someone to ignore the case and just read the text not noticing you have two different things named the same with different cases.

Comment: oh ok so I just have to be more creative with my names then

Comment: `then no you wouldn't be able to have the same name` That's not correct. They are scoped, you absolutely could name them the same. Your linter might complain, and it would be dumb to do that, but you can absolutely do it.

Comment: As for "probably bad practice", in this case, it's not even that. What's bad is that the state variable name is not a descriptive name. It has nothing to do with the fact that it's too closely related to the component name. I have no idea who in the world writes/reads code but "ignores the case".

Comment: I didn't mean intentionally ignore the case of course, it was more it can be easily overlooked when you're reading something and don't necessarily notice the difference in casing. Good point about the scope, I forgot about that I think I was thinking more with referencing the component name when you have a function name with the same name